Azure clasic storage migration services and code
I'm using the below NuGet packages to communicate with classic storage accounts. Here is the screenshot added.
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob

Reference used in .cs file

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Reference used in .cs file

Once the accounts are migrated to Azure Resource Manager, will the old NuGet packages (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.Azure.Storage) be able to call Azure Resource Manager (migrated account)?
I am working on the code changes (from Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob to Azure.Storage.Blobs), but it's taking more time than expected. Could not be able to deploy the changes before the deadline.
Note: NuGet packages are used in the console and library applications to call the storage account.
So, our question is: Will the NuGet packages Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.Azure.Storage be able to call Azure Resource Manager (migrated account) after August 31st?
If any Microsoft dev support team answer will be helpful.


So, our question is: Will the NuGet packages Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage and Microsoft.Azure.Storage be able to call Azure Resource Manager (migrated account) after August 31st?

According to this MS-Q&A by Sumarigo-MSFT.

If your cloud service only uses the older Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob library to upload and download files and doesn’t need to create, update, or delete storage accounts, you can keep using the library even after August 31st.

It's still a good idea to update your applications to use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) APIs for managing storage accounts. This will make sure your applications are using the latest and most secure methods for handling storage accounts.

if you decide not to update your applications to use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) APIs, you can still use the older Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob library for uploading and downloading files. However, you might miss out on the latest features and security improvements that Azure Storage offers.


If you plan to use the latest version of the Azure Blob SDK, you can follow this link.
